# Layout of UITableView header shifted down incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` where I've add a search bar, with these presets, to `tableHeaderView`.

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search by name or phone number"
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .Minimal
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

However, once I run the program, it's shifted down awkwardly. I've triple checked my constraints in my storyboard but it's set up correctly, as far as I know. Is this something that `tableHeaderView` does?

[image]

Comment: What is the top of the table view constrained to? If its to the bottom of the nav bar it will appear like this

Comment: Might need to set [automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets) to NO.

Comment: It is, but how do I change that or have it ignore it? I need the navigation bar present. Even when changing the top bar to inferred, the gap is still there

Comment: Tried `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried setting it in StoryBoard?

Comment: Setting what to storyboard?

Comment: Do you have a navigationBar in your vc in storyboard?

Comment: If not, set it there, check (and update constraints if needed)

Comment: I have a navigationBar in my view controller in the storyboard. The gap wasn't there before I implemented the search bar into the header view. Before this I simply had a list of contacts and no search bar that was all oriented correctly.

Comment: @j.f. I was trying to do it programmatically and it wasn't working, but when I changed in IB it worked wonderfully!

Comment: @ggworean - Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ScrollViews (including TableViews) automatically adjust their insets to account for navigations bars and the like. This allows the top of the content to start below things like navigations bars, but still scroll under them. However, depending on how you have your constraints setup, you may be already taking this inset into account. In that case, you can set the [automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets) property on the view controller to NO.

Programmatically:

```
// Obj-c
[viewController setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:NO];

// Swift
viewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Storyboard (attributes inspector):

[image]